# Unable to access custom properties on collection asset

Tags: linked-data, collections, asset-browser, custom-properties

I have one Blend file with a Collection that has a custom property with "Library Overridable" enabled. However, when I use the Collection as an asset in another file, I can't access the custom property.

Is there any way to access a custom property from an instanced Collection?